# Ubuntu 18.04 Error mysql_proc xampp laravel migrate

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have a problem with laravel.

**Local server:** *xampp 7.3.7*, **S.O:** ubuntu 18.04, **framework:** laravel, 
**Error:** database sql with store procedures not run.

when I try to use `php artisan migrate`, it shows me this error:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error:
>   1558 Column count of mysql.proc is wrong. Expected 21, found 20.
>   Created with MariaDB 100108, now running 100316. Please use
>   mysql_upgrade to fix this error (SQL: DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS
>   procedure_sum_pay)
>
> at
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/project-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:664
>
> Exception trace:
>
> 1   Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General
>   error: 1558 Column count of mysql.proc is wrong. Expected 21, found
>   20. Created with MariaDB 100108, now running 100316. Please use mysql_upgrade to fix this error")
>         /opt/lampp/htdocs/project-app/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:43
>
> 2   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1558 Column
>   count of mysql.proc is wrong. Expected 21, found 20. Created with
>   MariaDB 100108, now running 100316. Please use mysql_upgrade to fix
>   this error")
>         /opt/lampp/htdocs/project-app/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:41

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this answer comes a little late, but to solve that issue from MySQL you would simply need to run
`mysql_upgrade -u root -p`

Now if you are using XAMPP in Ubuntu, the `mysql_upgrade` file is located under `/opt/lampp/bin/mysql`, so you can run the above command once you are in that directory. Often by default user 'root' might not have a password set when using `XAMPP`.